# How does randomForest() predict for new factor levels not in training data?

Tags: r, random-forest

When I create training set and test set by splitting a single data frame and build a random forest using `randomForest` package, for some factor levels which are not present in the training data, the `predict()` function still throws an output. While this gives no error(which was what I was looking for in the related question), my question is on what basis does the `randomForest()` model predict the value, as it ideally should have thrown the following error...

`Error in predict.randomForest() : 
  New factor levels not present in the training data`

Want to know just out of curiosity if `randomForest()` method makes some inherent assumption for new factor levels in test data.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
seq1 <- c(5,3,1,3,1,"unwanted_char",4,2,2,3,0,4,1,1,0,1,0,1)
df1 <- matrix(seq1,6)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
colnames(df1) <- c("a","b","c")
train <- df1[1:4,]
test <- df1[5:6,]
```

Now when we create a forest using train and run the `predict()` on test as follow...

```
forest1 <- randomForest(c~a+b,data=train,ntree=500)
test$prediction <- predict(forest1,test,type='response')
```

The test matrix contain's prediction of '1' for the last observation which has a = 'unwanted_char' and b = '4'.

Please note: When you create test and train data **separately** the predict function throws the above mentioned error instead of predicting.

Comment: This is a great question, but I would phrase it as "How does `randomForest` extrapolate factor variables". Also, you're treading on some thorny issues with factor handling. I would suggest editing your question to use letters as inputs to make the factor issues clear. Here's a candidate rewrite: https://gist.github.com/geneorama/6aa6c343506c47b980f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that this is a very bad example; but, here's the answer:

Your created `df1` only has factor variables and 4 observations. Here, `mtry` will equal 1, meaning that roughly 1/2 your trees will be based on `b` alone and 1/2 on `a` alone. When `b == "4"` the classification is always 1. IE- `b == 4` perfectly predicts `c`. Similarly `a == 1` perfectly predicts `c == 0`.

The reason that this works when you create the data in a single dataset is that the variables are factor variables, where the possible levels exist in both `train` and `test`, although the observed quantities for some levels == 0 in `train`. Since "unwanted_char" is a possible level in `train$a` (although unobserved) it's not problematic for your prediction. If you create these as separate datasets, the factor variables are created distinctly and `test` has new levels.

That is to say that, essentially, your problem works because you do not understand how factors work in **R**.

Comment: I understood the part about factors but can you elaborate on 'mtry' equals 1. Do you mean to say that `randomForest()` only creates trees with a single variable in this case?

Comment: That's the implementation of `mtry` for your example. Read the help file and/or Breiman's original paper.

Comment: I don't exactly know how `randomForest()` generates trees but do you mean to say that each is made only of a single variable when you generate a forest? Will read Breiman's paper as you have mentioned, but just asking this to confirm a doubt...

Comment: see `?randomForest::randomForest`

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Alex that this is not a good example.

Here is the answer to your question:

```
       str(train)
```

If you check the structure of your train data, you will see that variable 'a' has all 4 levels, because the levels were assigned when you created the dataframe df1.